# Photoshop: how to produce this shiny bevel/emboss text effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to figure out the best approach to produce this effect.

[image]

Comment: To me, your example looks like a 3D render, or at the very least, not just layer effects on a single layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly achieve something very similar in Photoshop. Create a text layer and then double click on it to bring up the effects. Then add multiple inner shadows, emboss, etc until you get something that you like. You will need to uncheck the 'use global light' option in the effects so that you can move each effect independently. This can quite quickly get you something like this:

[image]

For more complex effects, such as the multiple highlights in the example image, you may have to create multiple images with different effects and then use different opacity modes to combine them.

Comment: Note that the multiple inner shadows are not possible before the CC version.

Comment: To have multiple inner shadows one can duplicate the orignal layer, set Fill = 0% and apply only the inner shadow to it. So in this example one would need 2 copies of the original layer, both with FIll = 0% and with one Inner Shadow each